# Uninstall all instances of memcached

Tags: centos, memcached, uninstall

My host asked me to: " You will need to remove
all instances of memcached that you have installed. "

How would i go about doing this?

I am on CentOS

Comment: What are you doing? `rpm -qa | grep memcached`? `find /usr/local/ -name memcached`?

Comment: Xlima. I am not sure this question really belongs here as this is basic RPM management.  There is no real issue here other than your lack of training regarding rpm management on Centos.  I suggest review some basic server admin items. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-lpic1-v3-102-5/

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to remove all instances of memcached from your CentOS server use yum to accomplish this task:

Use yum list to check for memecached instances:

```
yum list | grep memcached
```

Use yum deplist to check the list of dependances of this package before removing:

```
yum deplist memcached
```

Use yum remove to remove the package:

```
yum remove memcached
```

Comment: The first comman you mentioned shows you not only installed instances but also available packets. And you can do it without `grep`: `yum list installed memcached`

Comment: I just wanted to point out that `yum list installed memcached` is not exactly the same as `yum list installed | grep memcached`. Using `grep`, you are listing **all** installed packages and then only showing lines from the output that **contain** the word *memcached* (so non-exact matches like *memcached-devel* will also show up). If you just do `yum list installed memcached`, only packages with that name will show up (so *memcached-devel* would not show up).

Answer (score 0):

You could to use the following commands

```
rpm -qa | grep memcached

rpm -e namerpm
```