# memcached available, but not installed and unable to uninstall, but run in process

Tags: memcached, php-memcached

I installed memcached in my cent OS VPS. Somehow it's not work as i expected and now I switched to suPHP. But when I run 'top' command I can see 'memcached' run as a nobody user.

```
1727 nobody    20   0 58176 1004  652 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.64 memcached
```

Then I try to uninstall memcache using [this tutorial](https://serverfault.com/questions/315257/uninstall-all-instances-of-memcached), but ssh display following respond.

How do I correctly uninstall memcached?

```
root@host [~]# yum remove memcached
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: memcached
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.tocici.com
 * epel: mirror.pnl.gov
 * extras: mirror.tocici.com
 * updates: mirror.spro.net
base                                             | 3.7 kB     00:00
epel                                             | 3.6 kB     00:00
extras                                           | 3.4 kB     00:00
newrelic                                         |  951 B     00:00
updates                                          | 3.4 kB     00:00
Package(s) memcached available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal
root@host [~]#
```

Comment: Have you installed memcached with yum? Run something like 'rpm -qa | grep 'memcach*' to ensure the correct name within rpm-db .

Comment: It doesn't get any response.

Comment: I manually search memcached in WHM and deleted 'init.d' contain "memcached" folder. Then problem fixed. :D